# how do I remove one single element from an array dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

```
dict = ["H": ["hello", "hi"], "J": ["joker"]]
```

how do i delete "hi" from so dict it will look like

```
dict = ["H": ["hello"], "J": ["joker"]]
```

do i use ? dict.removeAtIndex(), if so how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexOf as follow:

```
var dict = ["H": ["hello", "hi"], "J": ["joker"]]


if let index = dict["H"]?.indexOf("hi") {
    dict["H"]?.removeAtIndex(index)
}

dict // ["H": ["hello"], "J": ["joker"]]
```

Xcode 8 beta • Swift 3 would be:

```
var dict = ["H": ["hello", "hi"], "J": ["joker"]]


if let index = dict["H"]?.index(of: "hi") {
    dict["H"]?.remove(at: index)
}

dict
```

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
let dict = ["H": ["hello", "hi"], "J": ["joker"]]

let dict2 =  dict.map { (key,value) -> [String:[String]] in
    let v = value.filter({$0 != "hi"})
    return [key:v]
}

print(dict2) //[["H": ["hello"]], ["J": ["joker"]]]
```

Comment: there is an extra [   it started with ["H"....now is [["H"...how do i get rid of that extra [

Comment: @EricYu update the answer ,what the dict look like